# Mysql GROUP_CONCAT and IN query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-concat, find-in-set

I have a table EMPDetails like

```
EmpID EmpName EmpFriendsID
1     Hari    2,3
2     Ramesh 
3     Suresh
```

I would like to have a query to retrieve EmpFriends name if i give an EmpID.

example if EmpID 1 is provided,result should be

```
1     Hari    2,3     Ramesh,Suresh
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is normalising your original table an option? Because that should really be your first priority here...

Comment: @LukasEder is right. the solutions below use FIND_IN_SET() which will get the right result... eventually. But it cannot be indexed, so it's bound to do table-scans of *both* tables. If you have more than a few hundred rows of data, you won't be happy with the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Join tables use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) and then group recors and use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to concatenate friends names

```
SELECT t.EmpID,t.EmpName,t.EmpFriendsID,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t1.EmpName)
FROM t
LEFT JOIN t as T1 on FIND_IN_SET(t1.EmpID,t.EmpFriendsID)
WHERE t.EmpID=1
GROUP BY (t.EmpID)
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c526bc/2)</kbd>

Comment: Hi @valex,thanks for the solution.I would be glad if i know how efficient the query works in terms of performance when have tons of records.Thanks again !

Comment: @user1650864 I agree with @BillKarwin and his comment to your question. Using this not normalised tables structure isn't performance friendly. You can't join these tables without a full table scan. Even if you have index on `EmpFriendsID` it can't be used. Instead you should create relation table for example `[EmpId,FriendId]` and instead of `EmpFriendsID="2,3"` you will get two rows in this table `((1,2)(1,3))`. In this case you can use indexes and this DB structure will be work much faster on tons of records.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**FIND_IN_SET()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function

Try this:

```
SELECT E1.EmpID, E1.EmpName, GROUP_CONCAT(E2.EmpFriendsID)
FROM EMPDetails E1
LEFT JOIN EMPDetails E2 ON FIND_IN_SET(E2.EmpID, E1.EmpFriendsID)
GROUP BY E1.EmpID
```